# Encapsular respostas de Requisições de Web Service RESTful no lado do servidor

Tags: php, web-service, restful, slim

Olá,

Desenvolvi um Web-Service RESTful em PHP usando o framework SLIM e um aplicativo android para consumir os serviços dele. Está funcionando numa boa, porém, as respostas de requisições GET, que são retornadas no formato JSON, ficam totalmente expostas quando eu acesso a URL do serviço diretamente.

Gostaria de saber como faço para encapsular essas respostas no lado do servidor para que assim elas sejam recuperadas apenas pelo cliente quando este estiver consumindo o serviço.

Comment: Você pode criar um token automático para ser gerado no aplicativo e ser validado no Webservice. Daí o resultado só irá ser mostrado caso o token tenha sido validado. Um exemplo básico seria criar um token com a data e horário da consulta e então o Webservice irá aprovar este token até tantos segundos após.

Comment: Ou, se o envio das informações é passado via GET numa Url, você poderia criar uma variável a mais, por ex: `&target=app_android` e no Webservice verificar se essa variável existe na Url.